# How to parse a large and complex JSON file to extract root elements only?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, parsing

I want to get a list of all the Font Awesome Pro 5.6.0 icon classes. There are loads!

This is the end result I'm seeking:

```
'500px',
'accessible-icon',
'accusoft',
'address-book',

// etc
```

I haven't been able to find a pre-compiled list anywhere.

But the download pack comes 4MB JSON file of metadata, which starts like this:

```
{
"500px": {
  "changes": [
    "4.4",
    "5.0.0"
  ],
  "ligatures": [],
  "search": {
    "terms": []
  },
  "styles": [
    "brands"
  ],
  "unicode": "f26e",
  "label": "500px",
  "svg": {
    "brands": {
      "last_modified": 1500927880000,
      "raw": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 448 512\"><path d=\"M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7 8.5-28.6 53 0 89.4-10.1 89.4-64.4 0-61-77.1-89.6-116.9-44.6-23.5 26.4-17.6 42.1-17.6 157.6 50.7 31 118.3 22 160.4-20.1 24.8-24.8 38.5-58 38.5-93 0-35.2-13.8-68.2-38.8-93.3-24.8-24.8-57.8-38.5-93.3-38.5s-68.8 13.8-93.5 38.5c-.3.3-16 16.5-21.2 23.9l-.5.6c-3.3 4.7-6.3 9.1-20.1 6.1-6.9-1.7-14.3-5.8-14.3-11.8V20c0-5 3.9-10.5 10.5-10.5h241.3c8.3 0 8.3 11.6 8.3 15.1 0 3.9 0 15.1-8.3 15.1H130.3v132.9h.3c104.2-109.8 282.8-36 282.8 108.9 0 178.1-244.8 220.3-310.1 62.8zm63.3-260.8c-.5 4.2 4.6 24.5 14.6 20.6C306 56.6 384 144.5 390.6 144.5c4.8 0 22.8-15.3 14.3-22.8-93.2-89-234.5-57-238.3-38.2zM393 414.7C283 524.6 94 475.5 61 310.5c0-12.2-30.4-7.4-28.9 3.3 24 173.4 246 256.9 381.6 121.3 6.9-7.8-12.6-28.4-20.7-20.4zM213.6 306.6c0 4 4.3 7.3 5.5 8.5 3 3 6.1 4.4 8.5 4.4 3.8 0 2.6.2 22.3-19.5 19.6 19.3 19.1 19.5 22.3 19.5 5.4 0 18.5-10.4 10.7-18.2L265.6 284l18.2-18.2c6.3-6.8-10.1-21.8-16.2-15.7L249.7 268c-18.6-18.8-18.4-19.5-21.5-19.5-5 0-18 11.7-12.4 17.3L234 284c-18.1 17.9-20.4 19.2-20.4 22.6z\"/></svg>",
      "viewBox": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "448",
        "512"
      ],
      "width": 448,
      "height": 512,
      "path": "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7 8.5-28.6 53 0 89.4-10.1 89.4-64.4 0-61-77.1-89.6-116.9-44.6-23.5 26.4-17.6 42.1-17.6 157.6 50.7 31 118.3 22 160.4-20.1 24.8-24.8 38.5-58 38.5-93 0-35.2-13.8-68.2-38.8-93.3-24.8-24.8-57.8-38.5-93.3-38.5s-68.8 13.8-93.5 38.5c-.3.3-16 16.5-21.2 23.9l-.5.6c-3.3 4.7-6.3 9.1-20.1 6.1-6.9-1.7-14.3-5.8-14.3-11.8V20c0-5 3.9-10.5 10.5-10.5h241.3c8.3 0 8.3 11.6 8.3 15.1 0 3.9 0 15.1-8.3 15.1H130.3v132.9h.3c104.2-109.8 282.8-36 282.8 108.9 0 178.1-244.8 220.3-310.1 62.8zm63.3-260.8c-.5 4.2 4.6 24.5 14.6 20.6C306 56.6 384 144.5 390.6 144.5c4.8 0 22.8-15.3 14.3-22.8-93.2-89-234.5-57-238.3-38.2zM393 414.7C283 524.6 94 475.5 61 310.5c0-12.2-30.4-7.4-28.9 3.3 24 173.4 246 256.9 381.6 121.3 6.9-7.8-12.6-28.4-20.7-20.4zM213.6 306.6c0 4 4.3 7.3 5.5 8.5 3 3 6.1 4.4 8.5 4.4 3.8 0 2.6.2 22.3-19.5 19.6 19.3 19.1 19.5 22.3 19.5 5.4 0 18.5-10.4 10.7-18.2L265.6 284l18.2-18.2c6.3-6.8-10.1-21.8-16.2-15.7L249.7 268c-18.6-18.8-18.4-19.5-21.5-19.5-5 0-18 11.7-12.4 17.3L234 284c-18.1 17.9-20.4 19.2-20.4 22.6z"
    }
  }
},
"accessible-icon": {
  "changes": [
    "5.0.0"
  ],
  "ligatures": [],
  "search": {
    "terms": [
      "accessibility",
      "wheelchair",
      "handicap",
      "person",
      "wheelchair-alt"
    ]
  },
  "styles": [
    "brands"
  ],
  "unicode": "f368",
  "label": "Accessible Icon",
  "svg": {
    "brands": {
      "last_modified": 1502397066000,
      "raw": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 448 512\"><path d=\"M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5 9.9-67.2 26L73 243.2c22-20.7 50.1-35.1 81.4-40.2l75.3-85.7-42.6-24.8-51.6 46c-30 26.8-70.6-18.5-40.5-45.4l68-60.7c9.8-8.8 24.1-10.2 35.5-3.6 0 0 139.3 80.9 139.5 81.1 16.2 10.1 20.7 36 6.1 52.6L285.7 229l106.1-5.9c18.5-1.1 33.6 14.4 32.1 32.7zm-64.9-154c28.1 0 50.9-22.8 50.9-50.9C409.9 22.8 387.1 0 359 0c-28.1 0-50.9 22.8-50.9 50.9 0 28.1 22.8 50.9 50.9 50.9zM179.6 456.5c-80.6 0-127.4-90.6-82.7-156.1l-39.7-39.7C36.4 287 24 320.3 24 356.4c0 130.7 150.7 201.4 251.4 122.5l-39.7-39.7c-16 10.9-35.3 17.3-56.1 17.3z\"/></svg>",
      "viewBox": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "448",
        "512"
      ],
      "width": 448,
      "height": 512,
      "path": "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5 9.9-67.2 26L73 243.2c22-20.7 50.1-35.1 81.4-40.2l75.3-85.7-42.6-24.8-51.6 46c-30 26.8-70.6-18.5-40.5-45.4l68-60.7c9.8-8.8 24.1-10.2 35.5-3.6 0 0 139.3 80.9 139.5 81.1 16.2 10.1 20.7 36 6.1 52.6L285.7 229l106.1-5.9c18.5-1.1 33.6 14.4 32.1 32.7zm-64.9-154c28.1 0 50.9-22.8 50.9-50.9C409.9 22.8 387.1 0 359 0c-28.1 0-50.9 22.8-50.9 50.9 0 28.1 22.8 50.9 50.9 50.9zM179.6 456.5c-80.6 0-127.4-90.6-82.7-156.1l-39.7-39.7C36.4 287 24 320.3 24 356.4c0 130.7 150.7 201.4 251.4 122.5l-39.7-39.7c-16 10.9-35.3 17.3-56.1 17.3z"
    }
  }
},
"accusoft": {
  "changes": [
    "5.0.0"
  ],
  "ligatures": [],
  "search": {
    "terms": []
  },
  "styles": [
    "brands"
  ],
  "unicode": "f369",
  "label": "Accusoft",
  "svg": {
    "brands": {
      "last_modified": 1505943678000,
      "raw": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 640 512\"><path d=\"M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2 23.4-2.4 1.3-114.6 47.7-117.8 48.9-10.1 4-17.5 6.8-30.8-9.3m114.7-5.6s-115 50.4-117.5 51.6c-16 7.3-26.9-3.2-36.7-14.6l-57.1-74c-5.4-.9-60.4-9.6-65.3-9.3-3.1.2-9.6.8-14.4 2.9-4.9 2.1-145.2 52.8-150.2 54.7-5.1 2-11.4 3.6-11.1 7.6.2 2.5 2 2.6 4.6 3.5 2.7.8 300.9 67.6 308 69.1 15.6 3.3 38.5 10.5 53.6 1.7 2.1-1.2 123.8-76.4 125.8-77.8 5.4-4 4.3-6.8-1.7-8.2-2.3-.3-24.6-4.7-38-7.2m-326-181.3s-12 1.6-25 15.1c-9 9.3-242.1 239.1-243.4 240.9-7 10 1.6 6.8 15.7 1.7.8 0 114.5-36.6 114.5-36.6.5-.6-.1-.1.6-.6-.4-5.1-.8-26.2-1-27.7-.6-5.2 2.2-6.9 7-8.9l92.6-33.8c.6-.8 88.5-81.7 90.2-83.3v-1l-51.2-65.8\" class=\"st1\"/></svg>",
      "viewBox": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "640",
        "512"
      ],
      "width": 640,
      "height": 512,
      "path": "M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2 23.4-2.4 1.3-114.6 47.7-117.8 48.9-10.1 4-17.5 6.8-30.8-9.3m114.7-5.6s-115 50.4-117.5 51.6c-16 7.3-26.9-3.2-36.7-14.6l-57.1-74c-5.4-.9-60.4-9.6-65.3-9.3-3.1.2-9.6.8-14.4 2.9-4.9 2.1-145.2 52.8-150.2 54.7-5.1 2-11.4 3.6-11.1 7.6.2 2.5 2 2.6 4.6 3.5 2.7.8 300.9 67.6 308 69.1 15.6 3.3 38.5 10.5 53.6 1.7 2.1-1.2 123.8-76.4 125.8-77.8 5.4-4 4.3-6.8-1.7-8.2-2.3-.3-24.6-4.7-38-7.2m-326-181.3s-12 1.6-25 15.1c-9 9.3-242.1 239.1-243.4 240.9-7 10 1.6 6.8 15.7 1.7.8 0 114.5-36.6 114.5-36.6.5-.6-.1-.1.6-.6-.4-5.1-.8-26.2-1-27.7-.6-5.2 2.2-6.9 7-8.9l92.6-33.8c.6-.8 88.5-81.7 90.2-83.3v-1l-51.2-65.8"
    }
  }
},
"address-book": {
  "changes": [
    "4.7",
    "5.0.0",
    "5.0.3"
  ],
  "ligatures": [],
  "search": {
    "terms": []
  },
  "styles": [
    "solid",
    "regular",
    "light"
  ],
  "unicode": "f2b9",
  "label": "Address Book",
  "svg": {
    "solid": {
      "last_modified": 1515426582023,
      "raw": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 448 512\"><path d=\"M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-228-32c44.183 0 80 35.817 80 80s-35.817 80-80 80-80-35.817-80-80 35.817-80 80-80zm128 232c0 13.255-10.745 24-24 24H104c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24v-18.523c0-22.026 14.99-41.225 36.358-46.567l35.657-8.914c29.101 20.932 74.509 26.945 111.97 0l35.657 8.914C321.01 300.252 336 319.452 336 341.477V360z\"/></svg>",
      "viewBox": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "448",
        "512"
      ],
      "width": 448,
      "height": 512,
      "path": "M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-228-32c44.183 0 80 35.817 80 80s-35.817 80-80 80-80-35.817-80-80 35.817-80 80-80zm128 232c0 13.255-10.745 24-24 24H104c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24v-18.523c0-22.026 14.99-41.225 36.358-46.567l35.657-8.914c29.101 20.932 74.509 26.945 111.97 0l35.657 8.914C321.01 300.252 336 319.452 336 341.477V360z"
    },
    "regular": {
      "last_modified": 1515426582015,
      "raw": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 448 512\"><path d=\"M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-74 304H54a6 6 0 0 1-6-6V54a6 6 0 0 1 6-6h308a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v404a6 6 0 0 1-6 6zM128 208c0-44.183 35.817-80 80-80s80 35.817 80 80-35.817 80-80 80-80-35.817-80-80zm208 133.477V360c0 13.255-10.745 24-24 24H104c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24v-18.523c0-22.026 14.99-41.225 36.358-46.567l35.657-8.914c29.101 20.932 74.509 26.945 111.97 0l35.657 8.914C321.01 300.252 336 319.452 336 341.477z\"/></svg>",
      "viewBox": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "448",
        "512"
      ],
      "width": 448,
      "height": 512,
      "path": "M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-74 304H54a6 6 0 0 1-6-6V54a6 6 0 0 1 6-6h308a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v404a6 6 0 0 1-6 6zM128 208c0-44.183 35.817-80 80-80s80 35.817 80 80-35.817 80-80 80-80-35.817-80-80zm208 133.477V360c0 13.255-10.745 24-24 24H104c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24v-18.523c0-22.026 14.99-41.225 36.358-46.567l35.657-8.914c29.101 20.932 74.509 26.945 111.97 0l35.657 8.914C321.01 300.252 336 319.452 336 341.477z"
    },
    "light": {
      "last_modified": 1515426582006,
      "raw": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 448 512\"><path d=\"M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-52-52v356c0 8.822-7.178 16-16 16H48c-8.822 0-16-7.178-16-16V48c0-8.822 7.178-16 16-16h320c8.822 0 16 7.178 16 16v60zM270.425 257.948C281.408 244.249 288 226.884 288 208c0-44.112-35.888-80-80-80s-80 35.888-80 80c0 18.884 6.592 36.249 17.575 49.948C107.25 270.543 96 305.706 96 326.363V340c0 24.262 19.738 44 44 44h136c24.262 0 44-19.738 44-44v-13.637c0-20.83-11.439-55.883-49.575-68.415zM208 160c26.51 0 48 21.49 48 48s-21.49 48-48 48-48-21.49-48-48 21.49-48 48-48zm80 180c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H140c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-13.637c0-17.859 11.839-33.555 29.011-38.461l20.641-5.897C187.017 285.859 197.261 288 208 288s20.983-2.141 30.348-5.996l20.641 5.897C276.161 292.808 288 308.503 288 326.363V340z\"/></svg>",
      "viewBox": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "448",
        "512"
      ],
      "width": 448,
      "height": 512,
      "path": "M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-52-52v356c0 8.822-7.178 16-16 16H48c-8.822 0-16-7.178-16-16V48c0-8.822 7.178-16 16-16h320c8.822 0 16 7.178 16 16v60zM270.425 257.948C281.408 244.249 288 226.884 288 208c0-44.112-35.888-80-80-80s-80 35.888-80 80c0 18.884 6.592 36.249 17.575 49.948C107.25 270.543 96 305.706 96 326.363V340c0 24.262 19.738 44 44 44h136c24.262 0 44-19.738 44-44v-13.637c0-20.83-11.439-55.883-49.575-68.415zM208 160c26.51 0 48 21.49 48 48s-21.49 48-48 48-48-21.49-48-48 21.49-48 48-48zm80 180c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H140c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-13.637c0-17.859 11.839-33.555 29.011-38.461l20.641-5.897C187.017 285.859 197.261 288 208 288s20.983-2.141 30.348-5.996l20.641 5.897C276.161 292.808 288 308.503 288 326.363V340z"
    }
  }
},

// etc
```

I'm thinking that all future versions will come with a similar file, so it would be really handy to have a method to parse out the icon names (which are the root elements).

Could I use any of the languages I'm comfortable with to do this?  I'm thinking one of:

- c#
- javascript
- jquery
- vbscript / classic asp (at a push)

I have parsed JSON using c# before, but needed a matching data model to parse into, and the data structure here looks pretty formidable.

Any help / examples / pointers would me much appreciated. Please say if I've missed any important info or could tag this better.

Thanks.

Comment: if you use json.net you don't need a data structure, you can query the document.  Also, if you do have a data structure and the json has extra things not in the data structure it will still work.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. So I could query it to say 'just get root elements'?

Comment: `Install-package Newtonsoft.Json`; `using Newstonsoft.Json.Linq;` `var result = JObject.Parse("datahere").Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList()`

Comment: `Object.keys(JSON.parse(jsonstringhere))` ?

Comment: Object.keys did it for me.  Thank you Jaromanda X. I was too lazy to try Newtonsoft when I could just wang it out in the same js file.  If you can post as an answer I'll mark it as correct.